# My pistons will not move unless I change the delay of a repeater

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Title. Not sure why this is happening, but I can only make the piston move if I change the delay of a repeater by clicking on it. I am trying to use this with a bubble column elevator, So I can't change the delay as the water will wash all my redstone away.

SS- https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcKLn.png

SS- https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAtld.png

Comment: Hi ItsConnall, welcome to Arqade! I'm having trouble understanding your issue with your screenshots being so cramped and up-close. I've also noticed several mods installed, which can potentially impact behavior. Can you open a new creative world in vanilla Minecraft and post a couple screenshots that clearly outline the issue at hand? Doing so will allow the community a much easier time to answer your question.

Comment: That's some very weird redstone circuit. For example, what is the redstone dust at the left on the first screenshot supposed to do? And do you have repeaters going into two blocks below the pistons that go into two redstone torches? If yes, why, and where does the signal come from? And what is your overall goal with this circuit? Just switching between magma blocks and soulsand? That can be done way easier.

Comment: SS- https://i.imgur.com/hEe0zOr.jpg This is the design I'm using, I'm trying to build a magma block to soul sand block swapper, and My issue is that whenever the soul sand and magma is in place, The pistons will push the 2 blocks where my pressure plates are, destroying them and moving the magma and soul sand way to much. I'm using a design by iskall85, that I took from a single frame of one of his videos, as he doesn't include any footage of the circuit in said video. SS- https://i.imgur.com/XKCrTz1.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure of that design but I just made this and it works: https://i.imgur.com/RJwDV3h.png [World Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fd4yrfkyomtx6xo/Redstone.zip?dl=0) Cords: 10 60 15

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the pistons a block update, I did so using observers. (You can use one if resource limited) though this design seems to suck me through the ground, I included another design I made in the world download also.

The repeaters are on a zero tick delay **It should be higher**, and the lower half is unchanged.

[World Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fd4yrfkyomtx6xo/Redstone.zip?dl=0) @ Cords: 4 56 44

[image: Top View]
[image: Side view]

Here is my design which I think works better, could be made more compact for sure.

The obsidian near the swapping blocks might be needed if you have this above the ground (as it might be pushed away)

The observers are completely irrelevant here and can be replaced with any block.
[image: Alternative Design]